# Access Check if a string field contains a char before doing something with it

Tags: ms-access

my problem is rather simple (i think), but I just can't make it work. I have numbers in a field that look like this 1;2.3  but sometimes they look like this 1;2.3 - 4;5.6
What I have to do is:
If there is the '-' char, get the first part (1;2.3). Otherwise get the whole thing. 
I did something to get the left part

```
Left([age_years];InStr(1;[age_years];" - ")-1))
```

but when there is just one part it gives me a #Func! result.
So I tried

```
mths: IIf(InStr([age_years]>0;"-");[age_years];Left([age_years];InStr(1;[age_years];" - ")-1))
```

but it didn't work at all. Gave me just a bunch of #Error!, and I cannt see what I'm doing wrong.

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
IIf(InStr([age_years];"-")=0;[age_years];Left([age_years];InStr(1;[age_years];" - ")-1))
```

You need to decide between " - " and "-", I have left it, but you should pick one.

Comment: Thank you! That was just silly of me to not notice.
(and the '-' thing was just me testing some possibilities)

Comment: It can be difficult, so sometimes it is worth deleting parts or adding default values when you are trying to debug.